# looping xml strings in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

What i am trying to do is get strings from my xml file, put them in an array, loop it in javascript so that each string will be displayed one by one on click of a button.

What I have so far is a JS array with the strings hardcoded:

```
<p id="all" > </p>
<input type="button" value="Increment" id="test"/>
<script>
var arr = ["data.string.name1", "data.string.name2", "data.string.name3"];

for(var i=0; i<=5; i++){
     $("#test").on('click', function() {
        $text= arr[i];
             document.getElementById("all").innerHTML= $text;
     });
};
</script>
```

I would like to remove the hard coding of the data and retrieve the strings from this xml (named data.xml)

```
<strings>
<string id ="name1">a.  this is the first string</string>
<string id ="name2">b.  He lives in Nepal </string>
<string id ="name3">c.  He lived in India for 7 years</string>
<string id ="name4">d.  He lives in Nepal.</string>
</strings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').on("click", function() {
   var doc=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
   var data=doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
   for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {      
        $text= data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("all").innerHTML += $text;         
   }  
});
```

See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_access.asp) for `XML DOM Access`

Comment: thank you very much but it is not working . It shows button but nothing happens when clicked

Comment: try this:  `$('#test').click(function(){` and keep it outside the loop.. see my EDIT